# Installing Scapy on a Mac: "ImportError: No module named pcapy"

Tags: python, macos, scapy

I'm trying to run a python script that involves scapy but I can't seem to get it to run. I keep getting this error

> ImportError: No module named pcapy

The script I'm trying to run is:

```
from scapy.all import *

def arp_display(pkt):
  if pkt[ARP].op == 1: #who-has (request)
    if pkt[ARP].psrc == '0.0.0.0': # ARP Probe
      print "ARP Probe from: " + pkt[ARP].hwsrc

print sniff(prn=arp_display, filter="arp", store=0, count=10)
```

I've installed XCode, XQuartz, Python, and Scapy using macports

Please let me know what I'm missing! #noob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing *libpcap* and its *Python* wrapper from source, as listed [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#install-from-original-sources), though the latest version is 0.6.4 and not 0.6.2:

```
$ wget http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/pylibpcap/pylibpcap-0.6.4.tar.gz
$ tar xfz pylibpcap-0.6.4.tar.gz
$ cd pylibpcap-0.6.4
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I solved this using following steps:

1.) Open **terminal** and enter the command

> sudo pip install --user pcapy

2.) Enter

> python

in your terminal

3.) Enter the command

> import pcapy

This should fix your problem.

Best regards,
Nazar Medeiros

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of pcapy from this link
https://www.coresecurity.com/corelabs-research/open-source-tools/pcapy

Unpack it and from the directory run the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```